# Generate custom chrome history?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

Is there a way to generate fake chrome history (it doesn't really have to be in chrome://history/). What I mean is that page should look exactly like chrome://history/

or maybe using chrome.history.addUrl to generate fake history, but the problem with that is there is no way to change the time for each url.

Let's say in history, I want to add url #1 with time 10:21pm, url #2 with time 10:41pm, and url #3 with time 10:51pm.

What I have tried so far?

chrome.history.addUrl -- but this only takes url not the time

chrome_url_overrides -- but if I use this then I have to make history page's html and css all from the scratch.

So how can I do that?
or maybe there is an api, external api (not even chrome api but external) which returns html + css or picture in which it shows a custom genereated history for chrome?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you try to change the chrome history sqlite database directly so that you will modify the history dates  according to needs

Comment: how can I do that through chrome extension? Thank you

Comment: you cannot do that through chrome extension directly, you have to use some sort of service or executeable running to access actual file system and to take the datetime from extension and then update sqlite file of chrome. exactly the way a downloader and it's extension in browser works

Comment: do you know where I can find more about the service or something which can do that? Thank you